# Automatically add screen shot to scheduled message in Outlook/office prank?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, scheduled-tasks, microsoft-outlook-2013

In Outlook (at least recent versions) it is possible to schedule messages, that is, write a message and then set it to be sent one week from now or similar.

I wonder if it is possible to schedule such a message and then, when it is about the be sent, automatically (=on a non supervised computer) somehow add a screen shot of how the screen looks at the moment the message is sent. The purpose is an office prank…

Comment: Sorry, no. Outlook 2013 has to be running in order for "scheduled" messages to be sent off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible in earlier versions of outlook as well, as this is part of Microsoft Exchange.

It is however not possible to somehow add a screenshot. When you click send, the email is transfered to the server, and the exchange server simply waits delivering that email. The email already is on its way.

Comment: @fixer1234 how so?

Answer (score 2):

With a slight change of approach, this would actually be easy.

Write a PowerShell, C# or VB.NET app/ script

- You can use .NETs screen shot / bitmap classes to take a screen shot and either copy to clipboard or save to an an image.
- Then use .NET's Outlook or mail assemblies to create a message to send directly through Exchange and bypass the actual outlook window. (after attaching the image of course)

Then you can use scheduled tasks to call the script or app.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to mark both your answer as well as LPChip's as accepted answer but the site only allows me to mark one answer as accepted.